# Undo "Delete Unused Images" - Codename one designer tool

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to automatically reload images deleted by the "Delete Unused Images" command? Exploring the project, in the theme folder I can see the deleted images, so I suppose that command only deletes references on theme.res file.

How to restore that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

These files are a part of the XML Team Mode. If it's enabled they might not be deleted at all which can occur either due to a bug on our side or due to disabling the team mode which might mean you have an older version of the theme still there.

XML Team Mode is designed for better versioning tool support as the binary res file doesn't lend itself to that.